# Convert array of objects to nested array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have the following array of objects:

```
[{
    "Lines": [{
        "Month": 10,
        "Year": 2017,
        "CompletionPercentage": 30
    }]
}, {
    "Lines": [{
        "Month": 10,
        "Year": 2017,
        "CompletionPercentage": 30
    }, {
        "Month": 6,
        "Year": 2017,
        "CompletionPercentage": 30
    }, {
        "Month": 12,
        "Year": 2017,
        "CompletionPercentage": 40
    }]
}]
```

I need to convert each `line` property to a separate javascript array

Line1 must be

```
[
    ["10-2017", 30]
]
```

Line2 must be

```
[
    ["10-2017", 30],
    ["6-2017", 30],
    ["12-2017", 30]
]
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get this result.

```js
var data = [{"Lines":[{"Month":10,"Year":2017,"CompletionPercentage":30}]},{"Lines":[{"Month":10,"Year":2017,"CompletionPercentage":30},{"Month":6,"Year":2017,"CompletionPercentage":30},{"Month":12,"Year":2017,"CompletionPercentage":40}]}]

var result = data.map(function(e) {
  return e.Lines.map(function(a) {
    return [a.Month + '-' + a.Year, a.CompletionPercentage];
  })
})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: It does return separate arrays for each line as you can see in console https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1062/

Comment: It returns 2 arrays the first array is always 0 length and the second has 4 elements , I need the first array must have one element and the second must have 3

Comment: sorry my bad I was testing on the wrong data it works fine thank you for your help!

Comment: I was wondering if there is way I can get them in sorted order lets say by month then by year?

Comment: Sure there is, but maybe you should ask that as another question.

Answer (score 2):

You could use nested [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and return all in an array.

```js
var array = [{ "Lines": [{ "Month": 10, "Year": 2017, "CompletionPercentage": 30 }] }, { "Lines": [{ "Month": 10, "Year": 2017, "CompletionPercentage": 30 }, { "Month": 6, "Year": 2017, "CompletionPercentage": 30 }, { "Month": 12, "Year": 2017, "CompletionPercentage": 40 }] }],
    result = array.map(function (a) {
        return a.Lines.map(function (b) {
            return [b.Month + '-' + b.Year, b.CompletionPercentage];
        });
    });

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function objToArray($obj, &$arr){

if(!is_object($obj) && !is_array($obj)){
    $arr = $obj;
    return $arr;
}

foreach ($obj as $key => $value)
{
    if (!empty($value))
    {
        $arr[$key] = array();
        objToArray($value, $arr[$key]);
    }
    else
    {
        $arr[$key] = $value;
    }
}
return $arr;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check https://jsfiddle.net/1qx6xqv4/

You can use nested `Array.map(function(data){})` to do this:

```
var data = [{"Lines":[{"Month":10,"Year":2017,"CompletionPercentage":30}]},   {"Lines":[{"Month":10,"Year":2017,"CompletionPercentage":30},  {"Month":6,"Year":2017,"CompletionPercentage":30}, {"Month":12,"Year":2017,"CompletionPercentage":40}]}];

var array = data.map(function (ls){
    return ls.Lines.map(function(line){
         return [line.Month + '-' + line.Year, line.CompletionPercentage];
})
})
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var abcd = [{"Lines":[{"Month":10,"Year":2017,"CompletionPercentage":30}]},{"Lines":[{"Month":10,"Year":2017,"CompletionPercentage":30},{"Month":6,"Year":2017,"CompletionPercentage":30},{"Month":12,"Year":2017,"CompletionPercentage":40}]}]
var array = [];
var secondArray = [];
var innerArray = [];
$.each(abcd,function(i,data){
secondArray = [];

$.each(data,function(j,lineData){

$.each(lineData,function(k,innerData){
innerArray = [];

innerArray.push(innerData.Month+'-'+innerData.Year,innerData.CompletionPercentage);
secondArray.push(innerArray)
})
array.push(secondArray)
});

})
```

Answer (score 0):

An ES6 answer

```js
const a = [{
    "Lines": [
        {"Month": 10, "Year": 2017, "CompletionPercentage": 30}]
}, {
    "Lines": [{
        "Month": 10,
        "Year": 2017,
        "CompletionPercentage": 30
    }, {"Month": 6, "Year": 2017, "CompletionPercentage": 30}, {"Month": 12, "Year": 2017, "CompletionPercentage": 40}]
}]
    
const r = a.map(e => e["Lines"]).map(e => e.map(e2=>[`${e2.Month}-${e2.Year}`,e2.CompletionPercentage]))
console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var lines = [{ "Lines": [{ "Month": 10, "Year": 2017, "CompletionPercentage": 30 }] }, { "Lines": [{ "Month": 10, "Year": 2017, "CompletionPercentage": 30 }, { "Month": 6, "Year": 2017, "CompletionPercentage": 30 }, { "Month": 12, "Year": 2017, "CompletionPercentage": 40 }] }];
var result = [];

for (i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < lines[i].Lines.length; j++) {
        result.push([lines[i].Lines[j].Month + '-' + lines[i].Lines[j].Year, lines[i].Lines[j].CompletionPercentage]);
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var object = [{ "Lines": [{ "Month": 10, "Year": 2017, "CompletionPercentage": 30 }] }, { "Lines": [{ "Month": 10, "Year": 2017, "CompletionPercentage": 30 }, { "Month": 6, "Year": 2017, "CompletionPercentage": 30 }, { "Month": 12, "Year": 2017, "CompletionPercentage": 40 }] }];

var outerArray = []
for(i=0;i<object.length;i++){
    var objs = object[i].Lines;
    var innerArr = [];
    for (j=0;j<objs.length;j++){
        var innerObj = objs[j];
        var month = innerObj.Month;
        var year = innerObj.Year;
        var CompletionPercentage = innerObj.CompletionPercentage;

        innerArr.push([month+"-"+year,CompletionPercentage]);
}
outerArray.push(innerArr);
}

console.log(outerArray);
JSON.stringify(outerArray);
```